# launch video every time splash screen disappears in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, mpmovieplayer

I am little bit confused about the behaviour.

What I want to do is,
I am having two different application.
One is made by me and other is by a guy who left the company & now I have to complete his projects.
But the task to be done in both project is same.

I have to show 5 sec video when I open the app every time.
Like Some branding video. (Done in angry birds app)

I checked all the links on SO, but didn't helped any one.

My senior who left the company, he have used Main.storyboard for navigation each screen.
and I am not that much good in using storyboard.
In my app, I created navigation programatically.

When my splash screen disappears,
I show dashboard.
But before showing dashboard, I have to show the video every time.
So what I did,
I created a view controller only for Video named `VideoViewController`,
and call that view controller from `ViewDidLoad` of dashboardView.
and when my video finished,
then by using NSNotificationCenter I removed the `VideoViewController`.

When I Nslog the url path, its printing correct, but My app crashes after that.
I checked it by applying ExceptionalBreakpoints, but didn't helped.

Here is my code to launch video in `ViewDidLoad` of `VideoViewController`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    NSLog(@"video path :- %@",url);
    playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    [playercontroller setContentURL:url];
    [playercontroller.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:playercontroller.view];
    [playercontroller play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:playercontroller];
```

and I am pushing `VideoViewController` from dashboard's

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

method.

As I am doing any thing wrong.
As My url is getting Nslg well, so no doubt of loading video.

Please guide me for the same.
also guide me to achieve same task using storyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to try like this [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController]; remove [self.view addSubview:playercontroller.view]; and then try

Comment: Or try like this [self presentViewController:playercontroller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @Darshan I tried the same but won't work.
then I switch to MPMoviePlayerController from MPMoviePlayerViewController. I have created object of MPMoviePlayerController not for MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: If I used MPMoviePlayerViewController and above line of code then app crashes giving following warning.
Attempt to present <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0x78f93c60> on <VideoPlayerViewController: 0x78f90d40> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't hardcode set the frame like that though..

Assuming 'self' is a ViewController (which has been properly addChildViewController'ed all the way from the RootViewController), try the next thing:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoFileName ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoController];
[videoController.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: :- App crashes giving warning "Warning: Attempt to present <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0x786e3a10> on <VideoPlayerViewController: 0x786e3d80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
"

Comment: make sure you addChildViewController all viewcontrollers all the way from rootVC to this one

Comment: I added my dashboard view as root view and once dashboard is loaded, then I call VideoView to show video

Comment: then, when adding this VideoViewController, make sure you do a          `addChildViewController:videoViewController` in the DashboardViewController

Comment: When I do addChildViewController:videoViewController, it does nothing, just freezes the app and console continuous prints the warning "[UIApplication beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]"